# Following method giving error in IE7 (method is to check filesize before uploading)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

```
$.validator.addMethod("checksize", function(value,element){
 var node = document.getElementById('pimage1');
 var check = node.files[0].fileSize;
 alert(check); 
 if (check < 2097152)
     return true;
 else
     return false;

 }, "Select image less than 2mb");


==========================================
JS ERROR
Line : 8
char : 17
Error : files.0 is null or not an object
code : 0
==========================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filereader is html5 feature. It might not work in ie. there is no other way either. You can use html5test.com to check which browser supports.

Comment: @Dynamic_Dude Most modern browsers support html5 features, so this should work.

Comment: IE still does not support lot of html5 features. Please check out http://www.html5test.com to see if your browser supports filereader.

Comment: na it doesn't supports :(
any alternative for the same ?

Comment: If browser does not support you can do it on server side. You can use mordenizr javascript to check the html5 compatibility.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess this is the only alternative now.
Thank you all !!